How to capture data from a TCP socket with scapy
I am creating a TCP socket:
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as server_sock:
    server_sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server_sock.listen()

    while True:
        sock, addr = server_sock.accept()

Then I want to use scapy to capture packets from the socket.
Right now, I'm doing it like this:
data = sniff(iface = 'eth0', filter=f“port {PORT}”, count = 1)

I receive one packet and send it to the queue. In a parallel process, I take packets from the queue and process them.
I am receiving packets from a network interface using a socket port filter. Is there any way to receive packets using sniff directly from the socket?
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as server_sock:
    server_sock.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server_sock.listen()

    while True:
        sock, addr = server_sock.accept()
        while True:
           data = sniff(iface = 'eth0', filter=f“port {PORT}”, count = 1)


Typically, if the protocol above TCP is HTTP for instance, you would do
from scapy.supersocket import StreamSocket
[...]

while True:
    sock, addr = server_sock.accept()
    sock = StreamSocket(sock, HTTP)
    sock.sniff(...)

If it's something else, you'd have to replace HTTP in the above example.
